# Create WordPress logic custom posttype

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have some problems with wp logic in my site. 
I have WP plugin with post type declaration file [(link)](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderDolgan/ea34ad107887469132b3) I create other page [(link)](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderDolgan/1d88faf4615ea4ab2568) with WP_Query create nav list using posts title's and the_permalink() method. 
After that, I create single-erm_menu.php (and try archive-erm_menu.php) for showing posts the_content().
The problem is that after following a link, I get to index.php

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you refreshed your permalinks?  WordPress sometimes caches its rewrite rules.  Just go to Settings .. Permalinks and save without changing anything (it may be enough to just go to the page, but I'm never certain).

Comment: after cleaning, I get on front-page.php.  I create another custom post by myself, and it is work normaly, i can't undertand the reason...